# SAS .gz file won't run..PIPE error

Tags: sas, pipe

I am trying to run the following code

```
filename hw&MONDATETO pipe   "zcat&WTDATADIR.MidMonthly_&DATEFROM._&DATETO..txt.gz";
```

but keep getting the error message:

```
UNOTE: The infile HW200611 is:                                                                      
  Unnamed Pipe Access Device,                                                                  
  PROCESS=zcat   O:\WTData\Monthly\v4\data\MidMonthly_20061014_20061113.txt.gz,                  
  RECFM=V,LRECL=256                                                                            

Stderr output:                                                                                     
'zcat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,                                       
operable program or batch file.                                                                    
NOTE: 0 records were read from the infile HW200611.                                                
NOTE: The data set WORK.HW200611 has 0 observations and 9 variables.                               
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):                                                    
  real time           0.10 seconds                                                             
  cpu time            0.03 seconds
```

I am running SAS in batch mode on Windows 2003 server.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to have a zcat  program on your Windows Server.  SAS cannot call a program that does not exist.

Comment: When running a system command make sure it runs on the system first then bring it into SAS.

Comment: gzip is installed on the server, and within the folder i see a zcat.exe file. 
I basically right click and submit in batch mode- (either 9.1 or 9.2), am I doing that incorrectly?